# What is Win10 Notification Icon / BalloonTipText max. length

Tags: delphi, winapi, windows-10

What is the maximum text length for Win10 Notification box texts ( BalloonTipText ) ?

Can there be a longer text somehow shown if the notification box is clicked by end-user?

```
procedure ShowBalloonTips(info: string; title: string; timeout : integer = 3000);
var
  TipInfo, TipTitle: string;
begin
  IconData.cbSize := SizeOf(IconData);
  IconData.uFlags := NIF_INFO;
  TipInfo := info;
  strPLCopy(IconData.szInfo, TipInfo, SizeOf(IconData.szInfo) - 1);
  IconData.DUMMYUNIONNAME.uTimeout := timeout;
  TipTitle := title;
  strPLCopy(IconData.szInfoTitle, TipTitle, SizeOf(IconData.szInfoTitle) - 1);
  IconData.dwInfoFlags := NIIF_INFO;     //NIIF_ERROR;  //NIIF_WARNING;
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_MODIFY, @IconData);
  IconData.DUMMYUNIONNAME.uVersion := NOTIFYICON_VERSION;
  Shell_NotifyIcon(NIM_SETVERSION, @IconData) ;

end;
```

Comment: [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/uxguide/ctrl-balloons) talks a little bit about limits (title has a maximum of 63 characters (48 to accommodate 30% for localization)) in the accessibility section. You can register actions when the user clicks the balloon and display a custom window with more text. In general I would keep the texts in the balloon itself concise to not overwhelm the user.

Comment: The question seems to imply that you are asking about Windows 10 Toast notifications, but the code uses the old Shell notifications (which happen to look like Windows 10 Toast notifications on Windows 10). [Quickstart: Sending a toast notification from the desktop](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/hh802768(v=vs.85)) explains how to send true Windows 10 Toast notifications from a desktop application.

Comment: Yes, Toast notifications can be created with the code above

Comment: No, they cannot. They merely look the same, but are fundamentally different.

Comment: Microsoft made balloon tooltips deprecated. Either use toast notifications or your own messaging. Toast notifications are out of user's sight, and pretty much useless as a way of informing user. Best to use your own GUI. Even plain old MessageBox does a better job than toast notifications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [_NOTIFYICONDATA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/ns-shellapi-notifyicondataa) structure defines the "szInfo" field to have a length of 256 characters including the terminating null character:

***szInfo**: Type: TCHAR[256]*

*Windows 2000 and later. A null-terminated string that specifies the text to display in a balloon notification. It can have a maximum of 256 characters, including the terminating null character, but should be restricted to 200 characters in English to accommodate localization. To remove the balloon notification from the UI, either delete the icon (with NIM_DELETE) or set the NIF_INFO flag in uFlags and set szInfo to an empty string.*

To change the balloon text issue another call to [Shell_NotifyIcon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shell_notifyicona) with NIM_MODIFY as the first parameter and just change the value of "szInfo".